# Custom Create User in ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I have made an asp.net MVC 4 Internet application. I wanted to have custom Create User function. So I used `CreateUser` function of `MembershipProvider` class and added `<providers>` configuration in my `web.config`.

But The problem is when I run the code it catches the exception *Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'*. Despite the database is generated by asp.net itself, it deosn't have any stored procedure (as previous versions had).

I can't use MVC 4's `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` function because it says it is not initialized.

So I don't know what to do. Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You are setting up a "create new user" function? Does the rest of your membership work (ie, log in, use validation attributes)?

Comment: The asp.net's default login still works (Like it's default register). But I haven't implemented the login. Maybe after solving this login would be the next problem.

Comment: Personally I would add a user to the DB manually and work on login before creating a new user. Are you building your own MembershipProvider or using the default one?

Comment: It is the default `MembershipProvider` and I didn't change anything. I am trying to implement a Login but I don't think that could be possible either, because it seems `MembershipProvider` uses stored procedure that my DB doesn't have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please use new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

`I wanted to have custom Create User function`

- If you want to take care of user authentication and authentication by yourself, you need to implement [Custom Membership Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) which basically overrides Default Membership Provider.

`exception Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.`

- you will not see that exception in new ASP.NET Universal Providers, because it doesn't use `SchemaVersions` table anymore.

Comment: That ASP.NET Universal Providers was enough. Thanks.